# Discord.py, how do I delete a role?

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord.py

I have tried and researched a lot of times but still could not find it. I want to make a command that deletes a selected role in the server. Here is what I came up with (Don't currently care about permissions):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await bot.delete_role(role)
    await bot.say("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
```

If you could help that would be awesome. I used role: [discord.Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role) and [delete_role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_role). Thank you for reading. If you have a solution, feel free to comment it.

**NOTICE:** This post was for the old version of `discord.py` and will no longer work. If you are looking for an equivalent solution for the rewrite (v1) version of `discord.py`, you can use the following code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, *, role_name):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name=role_name)
  if role:
    try:
      await role.delete()
      await ctx.send("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await ctx.send("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("The role doesn't exist!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to avoid being able to only delete roles that are mentionable

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, *,role_name):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role_name)
  if role:
    try:
      await bot.delete_role(ctx.message.server, role)
      await bot.say("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await bot.say("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
  else:
    await bot.say("The role doesn't exist!")
```

where you do `!delrole name_of_role` and use `discord.utils.get` to find the role by its name from the list of roles on the server.
Then if it's found you can delete it with `bot.delete_role` which takes 2 arguments, the server you want to delete the role from and the role itself

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Your script worked perfectly fine for me. I wish you a wonderful day or night.

Answer (score 0):

All you're missing is the `server` argument to `delete_role`, (which it shouldn't need, as every `Role` knows what `Server` it is from)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await bot.delete_role(role.server, role)
    await bot.say("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
```

You were already on the right track using [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters)

Comment: That command did not work for me but thanks for the effort, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions will not work `server` has to be `guild` and the actual role deletion can be a lot easier.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, *, role_name):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name=f"{role_name}")
    await role.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"[{role_name}] Has been deleted!")
```

**This solution is working as of 28/08/2021.**

Comment: You can also add a try statement to catch any errors.

Comment: Yes, but this post was about another version of discord.py. This post is no longer reliable and I believe that this comment is a bit unnecessary, especially after such long time has passed, but yes, this no longer works and you need to use `role.delete()` instead.